# Как реализовать функцию, срабатывающую в определенное время?

Tags: python

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать метод, который срабатывает в определенный час.

Предполагаю, делать нужно это в асинхронном методе (чтоб не мешала основной программе). Есть мысль только о том, чтоб через какое-то время проверять у системы который час (циклом) и, если час нужный, то выполнять какую-то функцию, но разве нет иного пути? На случай, если потребуется не час, а минуты.

Comment: 1. Использовать планировщик задач ОС. 2. Таймер.  3. Демон на Питоне? Оригинально.

Comment: Посмотрите на модуль [`shedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/). Кажется, это то, что Вам необходимо.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да, спасибо! Добавьте ответ и я отмечу его как решение

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для таких целей прекрасно подойдёт модуль [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).

***Пример из документации:***

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

А для того чтобы не прерывать выполнение основной программы, можно запустить цикл проверки в отдельном потоке или процессе с помощью стандартных библиотек [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) и [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) соответственно.

Answer (score 2):

Попоробуйте [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v3.7.0/userguide.html#), oн имеет ряд преимушеств по сравнению с schedule.

Документация предлагает следующий пример:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.sync import SyncScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

def sayhello():
    print('Hello!')

try:
    with SyncScheduler() as scheduler:
        scheduler.add_schedule(sayhello, IntervalTrigger(seconds=10))
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```