# запуск скрипта в питоне в определенное время

Tags: python

У меня есть скрипт, который должен запускаться в определенное время. Я новичок в языке Python и не знаю как сделать, чтобы скрипт запускался в определенное время каждый день. Помогите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать функцию, срабатывающую в определенное время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Comment: cron, systemd times, планировщик виндовс, автозапуск и держаться в фоне