# Дискорд бот и вызов условия проверки даты и времени

Tags: python, discord, sqlite3, pycharm, discord.py

я можно сказать новичок в пайтон и пока мне очень сложно разобраться в асинхронных функциях и тд.
Хотел сделать для бота дискорд, некую команду, чтобы человек отправлялся в поход на 6 часов. Я дал себе задачу сделать так чтобы ровно через этих 6 часов, человек возвращался из похода и бот уведомлял об этом участника. Пока сделал только внешний вид похода, его кд и занесение в бд время начала похода и его конца, но никак не могу сделать чтобы бот понимал когда ему нужно заканчивать поход. Помогите пожалуйста

```
@client.command(aliases = ['hike', 'поход'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 21600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def __hike(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    d = datetime.datetime.now()
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'**⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Поход⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀**', description = f'**{author.name}, вы отправились в поход который будет длиться 6 часов.**')

    emb.set_image(url = "https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/3510533/pub_5f280ab79e12c646d15eedb3_5f2e85b20d8f01499c464fa2/orig")
    emb.set_footer(text=f'виконав: {author.name} сегодня в: {d.hour}:{d.minute}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    d2 = d + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
    cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO Hike(UserId, TimeIn, TimeOut) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (author.id, d, d2))
    base.commit()

@__hike.error
async def __hike_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        author = ctx.message.author
        if error.retry_after > 3600:
            await ctx.send(f"**{author.name}**, вы сможете использовать эту команду через: **{round(error.retry_after / 3600)}ч.**   !")
            return
        if error.retry_after > 60:
            await ctx.send(f"**{author.name}**, вы сможете использовать эту команду через: **{round(error.retry_after / 60)}м.**!")
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"**{author.name}**, вы сможете использовать эту команду через: **{round(error.retry_after)}с.**!")
```

Comment: Может мне нужно добавить какой-то background task который будет сравнивать настоящее время с временем TimeOut в базе данных и если оно совпало будет выводиться возвращение из похода?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать функцию, срабатывающую в определенное время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

> ровно через этих 6 часов, человек возвращался из похода и бот
> уведомлял об этом участника.

Насколько я понял проблему, Вам лучше всего подойдёт библиотека *schedule*:

https://tirinox.ru/schedule-cron-python/

Comment: Реально, большое спасибо!!!Зачем придумывать колесо когда есть вот это