# Как сделать, чтобы бот в телеграмме отправлял в определённое время сообщение?

Tags: python

Написал бота в телеге, хочу, чтобы он в определённое время каждый день отправлял сообщение. Я новичок в pythone, несколько часов уже ищу решение.

Comment: cron? планировщик заданий?

Comment: Не шарю за API телеграма, но уверен, что модуль time поможет Вам

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать функцию, срабатывающую в определенное время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064445/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`aioschedule`](https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/). В ней можно настроить время выполнения каждый день (`every().day.at('XX:XX').do(требуемая фк-ция*)`), или же частоту выполнения (`every().hour.do(требуемая фк-ция*)`)

*Фк-ция должна быть асинхронной

Пример использования с `aiogram`

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule

async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(regular) #regular - ваша фк-ция рассылки
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```